# RoR Sorcery Routing Problem. Please help?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, routes

This has been driving me mad for two days now and any insight is very much appreciated.

Running Sorcery for authentication and everything seems to be setup fine, however when I go to register a user and enter submit I get a

Action Controller: Exemption caught Routing Error

No route matches "/pages/register"

However, if I visit localhost:3000/pages/register it shows up fine.

I've tried to change the users controller to redirect_to root_url (and yes the root is mapped in routes) but no change.

Any help???

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your routes and controller code?

Comment: You can use gist.github.com and provide a link to your gist.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1244148

Thank you!

Comment: What version of rails is this? Those routes don't look valid at all, and I've never seen anyone do a redirect_to like that.

Comment: Rails 3. I'm not sure about the routes, they could be wrong? If you mean the redirect_back_or_to that's a function in Sorcery.

Comment: I was actually talking about the get lines. They don't look valid to me

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the verbs. Most likely it tries to find a POST, while you have only GET defined